# Heater will blow warm air then go to cold

Tags: ford, heater, f-150

I have an 01 Ford f150 with the 5.4 Triton, my heater has worked good untill a few days ago, at operating temp the heater will blow hot air but if I change it from defrost to anything eles or turn it up it blows cold air, it doesn't change with engine speed, this morning it was -10° outside and my engine was trying to over heat, as soon as I turned up the heat the engine temp went back to normal, any suggestions